# PHP Twig extension error

Tags: php, twig

Im trying to create a twig extension

```
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__.'/../views');
$this->layout = new \Twig_Environment($loader, array(
  'cache' => '/../views/cache',
  'auto_reload' => true
));
$this->layout->addExtension(new \App\Lib\twig_microtime());
```

And App\Lib\twig_microtime

```
class Twig_microtime extends \Twig_Extension {

    private $start;

    public function getFunctions() {

        return array(

            'microtime_start' => new \Twig_SimpleFilter($this, 'microtimeStart'),
            'microtime_end'   => new \Twig_SimpleFilter($this, 'microtimeEnd')
        );
    }

    public function microtimeStart() {

        $this->start = microtime(true);
    }

    public function microtimeEnd() {

        return 'eeeee';
    }

    public function getName() {

        return 'microtime_extension';
    }
}
```

So at my layout Im trying to call {{ microtime_end() }} but im getting this error

**An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Argument 2 passed to Twig_NodeVisitor_SafeAnalysis::setSafe() must be of the type array, null given**

Answer (score 1):

First you define Filters in the getFunctions method, if these are Filters define them in the getFilters method.

Then the Twig_SimpleFilter and Twig_SimpleFunction object expects an array as the 2nd argument.

So try this:

```
public function getFilters() {

        return array(
             new \Twig_SimpleFilter('microtime_start', array($this, 'microtimeStart')),
             new \Twig_SimpleFilter('microtime_end', array($this, 'microtimeEnd'))
        );
}
```

But i guess you actually mean to create Functions.
This would be so:

```
public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
             new \Twig_SimpleFunction('microtime_start', array($this, 'microtimeStart')),
             new \Twig_SimpleFunction('microtime_end', array($this, 'microtimeEnd'))
        );
    }
```